# SDKMAN 5.5.9+231 says package is not a valid candidate on MacOS

Tags: sdkman

I have no idea why this started happening, but my SDKMAN stopped working and only displays the following message for whatever package I want to list, install, or use.

```
$ sdk list java

Stop! java is not a valid candidate.

$ sdk install java

Stop! java is not a valid candidate.

$ sdk use java 8u131

Stop! java is not a valid candidate.
```

Just typing `sdk list` works, though. But I can't do anything. My `.bash_profile` contains the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

export SDKMAN_DIR="/Users/myusername/.sdkman"
[[ -s "/Users/myusername/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/Users/myusername/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Comment: An issue has been raised in SDKMAN's GitHub repository: https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/587

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was on the server side. Something to do with SDKMAN's Candidates API. As pointed out in the GitHub issue, you can get over the problem using the following command:

```
sdk flush candidates
```

Make sure to **restart your terminal** after that.

Answer (score 31):

Also double check if you put the target sdk in front of the version. 
This won't work:

```
sdk install 9.0.4-openjdk
```

> Stop! 9.0.4-openjdk is not a valid candidate.

Specifying it correctly works:

```
sdk install java 9.0.4-openjdk
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue today. I was getting the same message after using `sdk flush candidates` and restarting the terminal.

So had to run `sdk update` and then restart the terminal. This added the candidates back.

Comment: Does this add value over nbkhope's accepted answer?

Comment: @greybeard Yes it does. I could solve the issue after following steps mentioned in nbkhope's answer. So my second line mentions what extra steps i did to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the following export

```
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh
```

was not at the bottom of `~/.bashrc` file.
It happened because I installed the other tools which ended up at the bottom of `~/.bashrc`.

When I moved it to the bottom and restarted the terminal `sdk` started to work.