# How do I install Spring Boot CLI in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, spring-boot

I am trying to install Spring Boot CLI in Ubuntu. I am new to spring boot and was trying to learn it. I have already installed Gradle and groovy but did not find anything online to install Spring boot CLI.

Answer (score 16):

please follow the code

```
sudo apt install unzip zip
curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
source "/home/username/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"=
sdk install springboot
spring version
```

Comment: I got "Stop! springboot is not a valid candidate." when I run sdk install springboot.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731320/7469332

Answer (score 3):

You can [read the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started-installing-the-cli) for installation steps:

**Manual installation:**

1. **Download** the Spring CLI distribution: you can find the latest version link [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started-manual-cli-installation).
2. **Extract** the downloaded zip file to any path of your choice.
3. **Prerequisite**: Make sure you have Java **JDK v1.8** or above (check **INSTALL.txt** file from extracted archive in Step-1). You can check your JDK version using command: `java --version`.
4. Add the **spring CLI script**'s path to `$PATH` environment variable:
   For example, you can add below lines to your `.bashrc` file in ***nix** systems:

```
export SPRING_HOME=/path/to/your/extracted-spring-cli/spring-2.4.0
export PATH=$SPRING_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

After saving the `.bashrc` file, run `$ source .bashrc` to reload the environment variables you just added.

5. (optional; and not for Windows user) **Shell auto-completion scripts** are provided for BASH and ZSH with the extracted archive in Step-1. Add *symlinks* to the appropriate
   location for your environment. For example, something like:

```
  ln -s /path/to/your/extracted-spring-cli/spring-2.4.0/shell-completion/bash/spring /etc/bash_completion.d/spring
  ln -s /path/to/your/extracted-spring-cli/spring-2.4.0/shell-completion/zsh/_spring /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_spring
```

To check if you are using BASH or ZSH, run the command: `$ echo $SHELL`.

6. **DONE**: To test if you have successfully installed the CLI you can run the following command: `spring --version`.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/08/28/install-spring-boot-command-line-interface-on-linux/) is detailed instruction on how to do it, much more useful than official one, at least for manual installation. One more thing - to make path change permanent you might need to logout - login, as "source /etc/profile" will be effective only for currently opened terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to get a detailed instruction on how to download the Spring framework successfully, It really helped me a lot after long time of making research.

https://www.decodejava.com/download-and-install-spring-framework.htm